# Assign result of function within switch to variable

Tags: php, switch-statement

here's some pseudo-code (it's not written correctly, the point of my ? is the variable, not the switch):

```
switch ($action) {

case "1":
//this is a function

case "2":
//this is a function

//etc.
}
```

How should this be written:

$variable = result of function in case 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your **`switch`** statement is wrong . It requires a **`break`** keyword between every case

```
$action = 1;
$result = "Success";
    switch ($action) {

    case 1:
    $variable = $result;
    echo $variable;//prints Success

    //this is a function
    break; // like this

    case 2:
    //this is a function
    break;//
    //etc.
    }
```

Comment: I know that.  Its a VERY simplified version.  I just need to know how to assign the result of the function within the case to the variable.

Comment: I don't see any function on your code. However, see the code that i have modified.

Comment: Switch cases are not functions, and don't have return values. The switch itself also doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the function(s) (you can pass args in too) as part of the code within the case / break blocks like this :

```
$action = 1;

    switch ($action) {

    case 1:
        $variable = someFunctionOne();

    break; 

    case 2:
        $variable = someOtherFunctionTwo();
    break; 
    //etc.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

how to variable the result of php switch.
ex:

```html
<?php
//variables of cases
$var_1 = 1;
$var_2 = 2;
$var_3 = 3;
$var_0 = 0;
//end variables of cases
//action variable
$action = 10;
//end action variable
    //start switch
switch ($action) {
  case "1":
    echo "$var_1;";
    break;
  case "2":
    echo "$var_2;";
    break;
  case "3":
    echo "$var_3;";
    break;
  default:
    echo "$var_0;";
}

//receives the value of the switch.
$switch_result = get_result_case;
//in this my example I need to enter the value of the case in a variable.
 ?>
```

in this my example I need to enter the value of the case in a variable.

Comment: suggestions : the code snippet there is **very useless**. And also add a language identifier to highlight the code and make it better to read